# Why "People" use "are" but "Everything" use "is"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Why "People" use "are" but "Everything" use "is" ?

Comment: Why? Well, language is arbitrary sometimes. *Everything* is a singular pronoun and *people* is a plural noun.

Comment: You question would make more sense if you compared "people" to "everybody", not "everything".  Whereas "people" refers to persons collectivelly, everybody refers to persons individually.

Answer (score 1):

People is the plural of person, so you would use "are"
However, Everything doesn't have a singular form or a plural form, we use "is".

Also, when we say everything, we are referring to singular objects in a group, which is why we say "where ARE all the things" but "where IS everything"